# Changing VB.NET code programmatically

Tags: vb.net, parsing, codedom

I want to open an existing VB class file, add a few properties and close it again.

Simple enough, I thought: Take the CodeDom, a VBCodeProvider, parse the code (using the Parse-method), then identify the location where I want my stuff added (doubtless using some nifty LINQ expressions), add a bit of code and then have it generated and here we go.

Now I see that Microsoft apparently added the Parse method only for the fun of it but never implemented it.

What's the story here? Can I only generate code from scratch? Is it not possible to load existing code?

Does anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You say "class files" and then you say "parse".  I think you meant "parse and modify".

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Visual Basic Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/VisualBasicFrontEnd.html) can do what you need on VB.net source code files.

DMS provides general parsing, AST-building, generic analysis and AST transformations, and is able to regenerate source text in compilable form. The Visual Basic Front End enables DMS to process VB.net, VBScript or VB6 and carry out any of these activities.

DMS's [Source-to-Source transformations](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html) can be used to make changes using "if-you-see-this, replace-it-by-that" patterns.

Comment: Good to know that there is a professional solution as a fallback option. I want to use this as part of a Guidance package. It is highly unlikely that we'd purchase yet another componant for this. Seems to be impossible with Microsoft-Tools :(